# How to handle upper or lower case in JSR 310?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

If a month is in UPPER or lower case, i.e. not Title case, DateTimeFormatter cannot parse the date.  Is there a simple way to convert a date to title case, or a way to make the formatter more lenient?

```
for (String date : "15-JAN-12, 15-Jan-12, 15-jan-12, 15-01-12".split(", ")) {
    try {
        System.out.println(date + " => " + LocalDate.parse(date,
                                     DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yy-MMM-dd")));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(date + " => " + e);
    }
}
```

prints

```
15-JAN-12 => java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15-JAN-12' could not be parsed at index 3
15-Jan-12 => 2015-01-12
15-01-12 => java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15-01-12' could not be parsed at index 3
15-jan-12 => java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '15-jan-12' could not be parsed at index 3
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`DateTimeFormatter`s are strict and case sensitive by default. Use a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` and specify `parseCaseInsensitive()` to parse case insensitive.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .appendPattern("yy-MMM-dd")
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

To be able to parse numeric months (ie. `"15-01-12"`), you also need to specify `parseLenient()`.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .parseLenient()
    .appendPattern("yy-MMM-dd")
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

You can also be more verbose to specify only the month part as case insensitive/lenient:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendPattern("yy-")
    .parseCaseInsensitive()
    .parseLenient()
    .appendPattern("MMM")
    .parseStrict()
    .parseCaseSensitive()
    .appendPattern("-dd")
    .toFormatter(Locale.US);
```

In theory, this could be faster, but I'm not sure if it is.

PS: If you specify `parseLenient()` before the year part, it will also parse 4 digit years (ie. `"2015-JAN-12"`) correctly.

Comment: @hraldK If `.parseLenient()` is not set the format "15-01-12" will fail.